# What is the parameter for Parcel.readStringArray()?

Tags: android, parcelable

I am trying to save the state in my `Fragment` through the use of `Parcelable`.

This lead to the following code when I wish to get back the a String array that I saved in the Parcelable:

```
public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            titles=in.readStringArray(???);
}
```

Now `readStringArray` needs a parameter, a `String[]`... But why? It could just give the Strings that I stored in it. I don't know a priori how many there were, so this sucks. :(

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readStringArray%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) says the following:

That is, nothing.

**EDIT:** If anyone has the same problem: I ended up using `writeBundle()`/`readBundle()` and putting my `String[]` into the `Bundle`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an implementation of this method from Android 4.1.2:

```
public final void readStringArray(String[] val) {
    int N = readInt();
    if (N == val.length) {
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            val[i] = readString();
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("bad array lengths");
    }
}
```

So it writes values to given array. And returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks! But... Why don't they just return a new array?

Comment: @Maarten don't know. May be creating new array is slower. Also I have second version of `readStringArray` method in sources that takes no arguments and returns array. But I don't see it in doc and can't use.

Comment: Did it work for you? I think you should accept @hunyadym answer I tried it and it just worked for me.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Could you promote that second `readStringArray` method to your answer? It seems real popular (judging from @hunyadym 's answer's upvotes)

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov I think yours is the better answer, even if the community thinks otherwise.

Comment: I don't get it. What should you put as the parameter to this function? How could you know the size of the array before calling this?

Answer (score 54):

Use `createStringArray()` instead of `readStringArray(String[])`. It will return the array you need.

Comment: @Maarten This is a much better **solution** to the problem, however, *Nikita Beloglazov*'s answer contains a better **explainiation** to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be useful to view these two methods, `readStringArray(String[] val)` and `createStringArray()` side by side:

Let's look at `readStringArray(String[] val)` method first. It requires a `String[]` as a parameter and might result in a `NullPointerException` if you pass a non-initialised array object (`null`). Also, you'll have to know exactly the length of the array (N), otherwise you'll get the `RuntimeException` thrown from the method:

```
public final void readStringArray(String[] val) {
    int N = readInt();
    if (N == val.length) {
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            val[i] = readString();
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("bad array lengths");
    }
}
```

Oh the other hand, with `createStringArray()` you don't need to form and provide a `String[]` as a parameter, it will be formed for you by the method with the correct length too, so you don't have to worry about either `NullPointerException` or `RuntimeException`:

```
public final String[] createStringArray() {
    int N = readInt();
    if (N >= 0) {
        String[] val = new String[N];
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            val[i] = readString();
        }
        return val;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

All in all, as a result of this basic analysis we can jump to conclusions and say that the second method is better and safer..